# Sending file through POST, Django/python request obj not storing correctly

Tags: django, rest, http, post, django-file-upload

I'm using a simple REST client to test. Sending a simple JPEG, tried the following content-Type(s):
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Also note csrftoken authentication is turned off to allow outside 3rd party REST connection.

(image is attached via the rest client)
Checked wireshark and the packet is setup according to the above parameter.

Django - request object has several variables:
request.body
request.FILES

After the POST is received by the Django server, the request object always stores all data/payload into request.body. Shouldn't an image or any attached files be going into request.FILES?  Is there something setup incorrectly on the content-type or POST.

very simple code. Just trying to print into the log. All objects in post keep going to request.body

```
def testPost(request):
     print request.body
     print request.FILES
     return HttpResponse()
```

Wireshark packet:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
POST /testPost/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: MYURL.com:8000\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Content-Length: 8318\r\n
Origin: chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36\r\n
Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4\r\n
Cookie: ******; csrftoken=**********\r\n
\r\n
[Full request URI: http://MYURL.com:8000/testPost/]
[HTTP request 1/1]
```

JPEG File Interchange Format

Comment: Please show us your code to help you :)

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres Added some more. Thanks! Anything else I should show?

Comment: Are your urls configured?

Comment: Yea don't worry about those.. just masking it so people don't see the public DNS. everything else is straight from the packet. @czarchaic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I handle file uploads: which in this case happen to be images. One of the issues I fought with for awhile was that request.FILES could come in with multiple keys and I always wanted the last one.

Note: request.FILES will only contain data if:

1. the request is a POST
2. the request has the attribute 'enctype="multipart/form-data"'

see the [Django File-uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) documentation for more details.

**The Model:** First there is a model with a ImageField in it: models.py

```
photos_dir = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/photos" + "/%Y/%m/%d/"

class Photo(models.Model):
   image    = models.ImageField(upload_to=photos_dir, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
   filename = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
```

**The View:** in views.py handle the post:

```
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

def upload_image( request ):

   file_key=None
   for file_key in sorted(request.FILES):
      pass

   wrapped_file = ImageFile(request.FILES[file_key])
   filename = wrapped_file.name

   # new photo table-row 
   photo = Photo()
   photo.filename = filename
   photo.image = request.FILES[file_key]

   try:
      photo.save()
   except OSError:
      print "Deal with this situation"

   # do your stuff here.
   return HttpResponse("boo", "text/html");
```

**The Standlone Poster:** Some python code to stimulate your django view.

Reference: I actually used this lib: [poster.encode](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/) to 'stimulate data' to my django view.py

```
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
import urllib2

server = "http://localhost/"
headers = {}

# Register the streaming http handlers with urllib2
register_openers()

img="path/to/image/image.png"

data = {'media' : open( img ),
        'additionalattr': 111,
}
datagen, headers = multipart_encode(data)

headers['Connection']='keep-alive'
request = urllib2.Request('%s/upload_image/' % ( server ), datagen, headers)

print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've been trying to use your Standalone Poster to send a request over, but it seems to be some sort of socket issue? I'm getting it on my local and the production server. I'm guessing the payload as well as the header needs to be "multipart encoded"?  Is there another way to retrieve the image cleanly besides in request.FILES?  Thanks for your help thus far @Jeff Sheffield

Comment: I followed your encoding example from python, and implemented on Java/ Google Glass, it works! thanks!

Comment: one last question, when you send a file encrypted, does it also get stored in request.body as well as request.FILES?

Comment: if you are referring to enabling server protocol https. Then yes it does get stored in request.FILES as well. Your django server view code will be identical. Your client code will of-coarse have to deal with negotiating the https protocol.